# How to access the content of my usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, user-controls

I created a user-control which is a button. When implementing the usercontrol into a parrent control, I'd like to set the icon and tooltip aswell as an enum property that indicates the buttons behaviour.

This is my Button.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Messenger.Controls.MainWindow.Button"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="30">
<Grid>
    <Button Name="btTabButton" Height="30" Width="30">
        <Image x:Name="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip x:Name="Hover">
                <TextBlock x:Name="HoverText"/>
            </ToolTip>
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

And the Button.xaml.cs

```
namespace Messenger.Controls.MainWindow
{
public partial class Button : UserControl
{
    public Button()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Image img;
    public Image Img
    {
        get { return img; }
        set { img = value; this.Icon = img; }
    }
    string hTxt;
    public string HTxt
    {
        get { return hTxt; }
        set { hTxt = value; this.HoverText.Text = hTxt; }
    }
}
}
```

(The function-selection is not implemented yet)
Here I call the usercontrol and try to set the property

```
xmlns:bt="clr-namespace:Messenger.Controls.MainWindow"

    <StackPanel Name="spButtons" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <bt:Button Name="one" >
            <bt:Button.HText >
                Test
            </bt:Button.HText>
        </bt:Button>
        <bt:Button Name="two" />
        <bt:Button Name="tre" />
        <bt:Button Name="for" />
    </StackPanel>
```

But I get an error-message:

```
"The member "HText" is unknown or the member can't be accessed"
//"The attached "HText"-property can't be found in 'Button'" This message does not appear anymore
```

Comment: Did you want `Button.HTxt`, when you tried to access `Button.IText`?

Comment: Yes indeed, I'll gonna change it right now.

Comment: I can't duplicate this behavior, but you may profit from reading about [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [DependencyProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @RaymondOsterbrink When I tried your code in a sample app I got a different compilation error "Because 'Button' is implemented in the same assembly, you must set the x:Name attribute rather than the Name attribute" - after fixing this, it complied Ok and didnt complain about HTxt. Also, you have a typo HText instead of HTxt

Comment: @Raymond - If you want binding support as well. Consider creating them as dependency property.